# How to store full name as first name + last name from ejs file to database?

Tags: database, mongodb, express, ejs, string-concatenation

I have written the following code to take first name and last name as input from user in ejs file. Now, I want to store the full name in database. How can I achieve that?

Code in ejs file:

```
<label for="Lname" class="abc"> Legal Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="L1name" name="firstName" placeholder="First name">
<input type="text" id="Lname" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
```

Code in models.js:

```
const employeeinfocenterschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    fullName: {
        type: String,
        
    },
});
```

How to get fullName here?

Comment: By setting the `fullName` to the first + last names before creating the object you send? That said, since it's a calculated field, do you really need to store it? (There are valid reasons to duplicate data, but it may not be necessary.)

Comment: Yes, I have to store it because I want full names in a dropdown in another form.

Comment: How do I set fullName as firstname + lastname here?

Comment: You don't right here. You set it when you take the input values and set them on the object you're sending to the back end. That you need the full names in a different form is not directly related--you can calculate it then as well, or use a [virtual function](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) for data that is in the model but not persisted to the DB.

Comment: How do I achieve that? Can you please share the syntax?

Comment: Achieve what? How do you save the data now? Where you save the data set `fullName` to `${firstName} ${lastName}` or whatever your values are called. Create a virtual function? See the docs I linked to.